# Cycle through labels in enumeration

Tags: formatting, enumerate

I'm trying to make a template for science exercises, the way our students have to solve them in secondary school, using the keywords "Given", "Asked" and "Solution" in the margin. I used Latex quite a lot some years ago, but forgot a lot since.

First of all, I'd like to find a way to automatically cycle through these three labels (every question needs to use each label only once). Is it possible to choose a string from a list or an array based on a counter, or something like that?

Second, I don't really dig the workflow I constructed below, needing to make environments in environments and so on. I would like to construct something like

```
\begin{question}{3}
    Question Three in words
    \given Something automatically in math mode
    \asked Something automatically in math mode
    \sol (No bullet when only a single step)
        \step First step, math mode
        \step First step, math mode
\end{question}
```

---

This is my code. As you can see, I only get the keyword "given:" so far

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=1in, reversemp]{geometry}

\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[exercise]{wide = 0pt, listparindent=\parindent,labelsep = 0pt,leftmargin =\labelwidth}
\setlist[exercise, 1]{label =\llap{\textbf{Ex~\arabic*.}\hskip\marginparsep}}
\setlist[exercise, 2]{label = \itshape Given:, labelwidth = 3.5em, leftmargin =\labelwidth}
\setlist[exercise, 3]{label=$\bullet$,labelwidth = 1.333em, leftmargin =\labelwidth}
\let\cat\item
\let\step\item

\begin{document}    
\begin{exercise}
\item Calculate the volume of a cylinder with a radius of 2m and a height of 3m.
    \begin{exercise}
        \cat $r = 2 \qquad h = 3$
        \cat $V$
        \cat
        \begin{exercise}
            \step $A = 2 \pi r = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 2 \Rightarrow A = 12.57 m^2$
            \step $V = A h = 12.57 \cdot 3 \Rightarrow V = 37.70 m^3$
        \end{exercise}
    \end{exercise}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on a few assumptions:

1. There is only one `\asked` item
2. There is no text after `\sol`
3. If there is only one step, no `\step` command is used

Here's the code, with comments.

```
\errorcontextlines=100
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,enumitem,environ,expl3}

\newcounter{exercise}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{exercise}
 {
  \refstepcounter{exercise}
  \begin{itemize}[label=\textbf{Ex.\@~\theexercise},leftmargin=*]
  \exercise_process:V \BODY
  \end{itemize}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \exercise_process:n
 {
  % split the input at \sol
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_exercise_body_seq { \sol } { #1 }
  % get the part before \sol
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_exercise_body_seq \l_exercise_body_tl
  % get the part after \sol
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_exercise_body_seq \l_exercise_sol_tl
  % split the input at \asked
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_exercise_body_seq { \asked } \l_exercise_body_tl
  % get the part before \asked
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_exercise_body_seq \l_exercise_body_tl
  % get the asked part
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_exercise_body_seq \l_exercise_asked_tl
  % split the input at \given
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_exercise_body_seq { \given } \l_exercise_body_tl
  % get the part before \given
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_exercise_body_seq \l_exercise_text_tl
  % save the \given part
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l_exercise_given_seq \l_exercise_body_seq

  %%% Now put the pieces together
  % issue the text
  \item \tl_use:N \l_exercise_text_tl
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  % process the \given part
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_exercise_given_seq { \item[given:] $##1$ }
  % process the \asked part
  \item[asked:] $\tl_use:N \l_exercise_asked_tl$
  % process the \sol part
  \item[solution:]
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_exercise_body_seq { \step } \l_exercise_sol_tl
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_exercise_body_seq = 1 }
   { % only one step
     $\tl_use:N \l_exercise_sol_tl$
   }
   { % more steps
    % throw away the first (empty) item
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l_exercise_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \begin{itemize}[label=\textbullet]
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_exercise_body_seq { \item $##1$ }
    \end{itemize}
   }
  \end{itemize}
 }
\tl_new:N \l_exercise_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l_exercise_asked_tl
\tl_new:N \l_exercise_sol_tl
\seq_new:N \l_exercise_body_seq
\seq_new:N \l_exercise_given_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \exercise_process:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Calculate the length of a circle of radius \SI{1}{m}
  \given r=1
  \asked L
  \sol L = 2 \pi r = 2\cdot\pi\cdot 1\Rightarrow L = \SI{6.28}{m}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Calculate the volume of a cylinder with a 
radius of \SI{2}{m} and a height of \SI{3}{m}.
  \given r = 2
  \given h = 3
  \asked V
  \sol
    \step A = 2 \pi r = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 2 \Rightarrow A = \SI{12.57}{m^2}
    \step V = A h = 12.57 \cdot 3 \Rightarrow V = \SI{37.70}{m^3}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quite a lot of syntax and comments that are new to me, but it does exactly what I wanted :D

Answer (score 0):

A little different than *how* you asked it to be, but this is how I'd do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=1in, reversemp]{geometry}

\newcommand{\given}[1]{\item[Given:] $#1$}
\newcommand{\asked}[1]{\item[Asked:] $#1$}
\let\step\item
\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]{\stepcounter{exercise}
                                \begin{itemize}
                                \item[\bfseries Ex \theexercise.] #1
                                \begin{itemize}
                        }{
                        \end{itemize}
                        \end{itemize}
                        }
\newenvironment{sol}{\begin{itemize}[label={}]}{\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{exercise}{Calculate the volume of a cylinder with a radius of 2m and a height of 3m.}
        \given{r = 2 \qquad h = 3}
        \asked{V}
        \begin{sol}
            \step $A = 2 \pi r = 2 \cdot \pi \cdot 2 \Rightarrow A = 12.57 m^2$
            \step $V = A h = 12.57 \cdot 3 \Rightarrow V = 37.70 m^3$
        \end{sol}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

The `exercise` environment has an argument which is the Question's text, the exercise number is automatic. Instead of making a `sol` command it was made an environment so there can be many steps.